# Min Priority Queue with custom comparator

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am working on a sorting function that uses a priority queue. The function is templated and takes in custom comparators:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
void sort (std::vector<T>& myArray, Comparator comp) {}
```

The function creates a priority queue:

```
std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Comparator > pQueue;
```

Currently, `top()` and `pop()` returns and pops the highest value.

However, I am looking for a min priority queue that returns and pops the lowest value when using the `top()` and `pop()` functions. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Change the return of the comparator to its negative? (using `!`)

Comment: Unfortunately the comparator cannot be changed

Comment: Why? You want a priority queue with low instead of high, then use the opposite comparator, and that's it.

Comment: The test cases I am running it against have comparators which cannot be altered

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making `pop()` and `top()` not the way it is supposed to behave for the given comparator?

Answer (score 3):

Just *swap* the arguments given to your `Comparator` object:

```
auto cmp = [](auto a, auto b) { return Comparator()(b, a); };
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

---

Note that your `Comparator` (i.e., the [`Compare` in `std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)) must provide *strict weak ordering*.

> A `Compare` type providing a strict weak ordering.

However, the lambda expression

```
auto cmp = [](auto a, auto b) { return !Comparator()(a, b); };
```

may not provide a strict weak ordering. For example, if `Comparator()(a, b)` is defined to be `a < b`, then `!Comparator()(a, b)` would be equivalent to `!(a < b)`, which is in turn equivalent to `a >= b` and definitely different from `a > b`.

Unlike the `>` operator, the `>=` operator is a *binary relation*<sup>1</sup> that does not provide *strict weak ordering* because *strictness*<sup>2</sup> does not hold, since it is true that `a >= a`, i.e., it is actually *reflexive*<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>(1) A *binary relation* is just a binary *predicate*, i.e., a boolean function taking two parameters, e.g., the relational operators or the `operator()` member function of `std::less<int>`.</sup>

<sup>(2) A binary relation it is said to be *strict*, if it **never holds** for an element and itself, e.g., `<`, since `a < a` never holds.</sup>

<sup>(3) A binary relation it is said to be *reflexive*, if it **always holds** for an element and itself, e.g., `<=`, since `a <= a` always holds.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`std::priority_queue` is a max-heap (by default) and only the largest element is available.  If you want it to be a min-heap then you need to reverse the sorting condition.  So, if `comp(a, b)` would return `true` if `a < b` then we need to swap `a` and `b` to turn the `std::priority_queue` into a min-heap.  That would look like

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
void sort (std::vector<T>& myArray, Comparator comp)
{
    auto comp_reverse = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return comp(rhs, lhs); };
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, decltype(comp_reverse)> pQueue;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the comparator in something that swaps the order of parameters.

`a < b` is exactly equal to `b > a`.

```
template <typename Comparator>
struct invert
{
     template <typename Right, typename Left>
     bool operator()(Right&& rhs, Left&& lhs)
     { return comp(std::forward<Left>(lhs), std::forward<Right>(rhs)); }
     Comparator comp;
};

template <class T, class Comparator>
void sort (std::vector<T>& myArray, Comparator comp) 
{
    std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, invert<Comparator> > pQueue(comp);
    // ...
}
```